# Timer Threading - AttributeError '...' has no attribute '...'

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

As I'm new in python maybe I'm missing the obvious.

I've wrote the updateRates method for the class which counts fps in this RDP program.

When I try to access some attributes from inside the call from the timer method there is this weird Error:

**"AttributeError: type object 'RDCToGUI' has no attribute '_cnt_framerate'"**

it is really obvious this class inherits this attribute, but *in the **Timer thread*** it doesn't seem to be there anymore

**So the problem is: I can call the inherited methods of the super (e.g. self.rates) but *inside* some attributes aren't present in the method**

```
class RDCToGUI(clientProtocol.rdc):
    def __init__(self):
        clientProtocol.rdc.__init__(self)
        self.num = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.framerate_before = 0

    def updateRates(self, framerate_label, datarate_label):
        divisor = 1
        datarate_text = "b/s"

        self.rates(self)
        framerate = self.framerate
        datarate = self.datarate

        if self.logged_in == 1 and self.framerate_before == 0 == framerate:
            self.framebufferUpdateRequest(
                width=800, height=800)
        if datarate > 1000000:
            divisor = 1000000
            rateText = "Mb/s"
        elif datarate > 1000:
            divisor = 1000
            rateText = "Kb/s"

        self.framerate_before = framerate

        framerate_label.setText(f"Framerate: {framerate}")
        datarate_label.setText(
            f"Datarate: {round(datarate / divisor, 2)} {datarate_text}")

        threading.Timer(1, self.updateRates, args=(self,
                                                   framerate_label, datarate_label)).start()
```

```
class rdc(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self._packet = ""
        self._expected_len = 0
        self._cnt_framerate = 0
        self._cnt_datarate = 0
        self.framerate = 0
        self.datarate = 0
        self.logged_in = 0

    def rates(self):
        self.setRates(self)
        self.resetCounter(self)

    def setRates(self):
        self.framerate = self._cnt_framerate
        self.datarate = self._cnt_datarate

    def resetCounter(self):
        self._cnt_datarate = 0
        self._cnt_framerate = 0

    def incFramerate(self):
        self._cnt_framerate += 1

    def addDataSize(self, size):
        self._cnt_datarate += size
```

The classes have more methods and members than what I showed, but wanted to cut it to the most important stuff.

Tried to put the method in different classes and played around with the names of the attributes

class rdc is **in another file** which is imported as clientProtocol.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an inheritance issue. Maybe try replacing

```
clientProtocol.rdc.__init__(self)
```

with

```
super(RDCToGUI, self).__init__()
```

I'm not an expert on inheritance either and haven't really used it, but there is a ton to read on the `super()` function and you could maybe start at [Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) and just follow it down the rabbit hole :)

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve the problem. The inheritance seems correct though, because I can call the methods of the super class but some attributes disappear in context to the threading of the timer.